# Editing a lookup file consumed by a Python program during its execution

Tags: python

I have a Python program which starts in the morning and ends at midnight, sleeping during the day intermittently for small intervals if there are no tasks to work on. Just before midnight, it reads a lookup file and takes necessary actions based on its contents.

If I modify the contents of the lookup file during the day when the program is running, will it consider the modified contents of the file or the contents of the file as of the morning before it starts running?

Essentially, will the Python program consider the state of the file the moment it is read in the code or the moment it started running.

P.S: The lookup file is referred and read only at midnight and not at any point in the day.

Comment: Depends on how you read it in the code, but if you properly open and close the file in your code only when you need to read the file, it should use whatever version is saved in the specified location at the time of the `open` call.

Comment: The file is opened with a context manager and an `open` call.